# This one is about YOU! (and other things)

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, language

> This first one is just you plus...
>   ...dwarfs in Snow White,
>   ...bits in a byte,
>   ...tripod's upright,
>   ...and a number that is quite lucky at least in my opinion.
>
> Then there's you plus...
>   ...wonders of yore,
>   ...pawns set for war,
>   ...cat's lives in store,
>   ...and the black ball in a game which has also different colours.
>
> And then, the third one is you plus...
>   ...men's power rings,
>   ...bass guitar's strings,
>   ...insect that stings,
>   ...and one hundred in a system which uses letters to represent numbers.
>
> Finally, you plus...
>   ...time span maternal,
>   ...man's limbs external,
>   ...circles infernal,
>   ...and the smallest card in the deck if you are playing a game where the aces are high.

The final answer is a surname.

Comment: Jafe, your body of work when it comes to unique puzzles is quite impressive! +1

Comment: Thanks @El-Guest! You've solved quite a few of them yourself, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: and they’ve been fun every time!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each stanza refers to

> A unicode character.  This is clued by the "You" (U) at the beginning of each.

The solutions are as follows:

#### Stanza 1

> **7** dwarfs in Snow White
>  **8** bits in a byte
>  **3** legs on a tripod
>  **7** is a lucky number in most of the West

This makes

> U+7837, or 砷, which is **Arsenic**.

#### Stanza 2

> **7** wonders of yore (ancient wonders of the world)
>  **8** pawns set for war (on one side of a chess board)
>  **9** cat's lives in store (cats are commonly said to have 9 lives)
>  **8**-ball in pool, snooker and similar games

This makes

> U+7898, or 碘, which is **Iodine**.

#### Stanza 3

> **9** men's power rings (rings of power from Lord of the Rings)
>  **4** bass guitar's strings
>  **B** (or bee) is an insect that stings
>  **C** is one hundred in Roman numerals

This makes

> U+94BC, or 钼, which is **Molybdenum**.

#### Stanza 4

> **9** months of gestation (time span maternal)
>  **4** limbs on a man
>  **9** circles of hell in Dante's *Inferno*
>  **2** is the smallest card if aces are high

This makes

> U+9492, or 钒, which is **Vanadium**.

Putting these together, we have

> **As** + **I** + **Mo** + **V** (the symbols for the listed elements)
>  or **ASIMOV**, a [famous science-fiction author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov).

Comment: Swoop! There it is! Great answer GPR! :D

Comment: I got thrown off by the damn dwarves and trusted my memory rather than google >_<

Answer (score 7):

The name is:

> <s>蠷碘钼钒 or 蠽碘钼钒 which I can only assume are Chinese surnames. But all google says is Molybdenum Kitchen Knives.</s>  Combining the element symbols gives ASIMOV which is a surname!

The first one is:

> 7 Dwarfs in Snow White,
>  8 bits in a byte,
>  3 legs in a tripod,
>  7 can be considered lucky.
>  Giving **U+7837**
>  Which represents 砷
>  Which translates to Arsenic
>  Which has abbreviation As

The second one is:

> 7 wonders of the world,
>  8 pawns per side in chess,
>  9 cat's lives,
>  8 ball in pool.
>  Giving **U+7898**
>  Which is 碘,
>  Which translates to Iodine
>  Which has the abbreviation I

The third one is:

> 9 rings of power in lotr given to men
>  4 bass guitar strings,
>  b (bee) stings,
>  c 100 in roman numerals,
>  Giving **U+94bc**
>  Which is 钼
>  Which translates to Molybdenum,
>  Which has the abbreviation MO

The fourth one is:

> 9 months in a pregnancy,
>  4 human limbs
>  9 circles of hell
>  2 is the smallest card (other than Ace)
>  Giving **U+9492**
>  Which is 钒
>  Which translates to Vanadium
>  Which has the abbreviation V