# Michael Myers left me a note!

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, cipher

I came back from my run the other day and found this note left on my kitchen table. It was a terrifying experience when I learned it was from the masked psychopath Michael Myers himself. I really don't understand what it says; hopefully you can help me before my time is up!

---

> 1. afwpjhs ovyyvy tvcpl aptl + mlthsl ovyzl
> 2. zvtlaopun pujhyuhal
> 3. aol mvn dhz kluzl, huk pa dhz khyr; hz aol upnoa whzzlk if, ivul iylhrpun ovdsz iyvrl aoyvbno aol ayllz; aopz zlaapun dhz? l3?
> 4. aophdy
> 5. nylha ovyu, ihyu, zuvdf, ihyylk, ibyyvdpun, lsm
> 6. thkl myvt h tlahs myhtl dpao zlclyhs zpklz (bzbhssf mvby, iba bw av lpnoa), > jvttvusf dpao h ovvr vy ovvw vm tlahs vu avw
> 7. oaawz://p.zahjr.ptnby.jvt/2cuDb.qwn
> 8. Tlayvthu pz ihjr myvt aol klhk!
> 9. Lkkpl Tbywof hz Qpt Lclyz
> 10. WZL?73479
> 11. tvauhow
> 12. tpeabyl, iyld, lspepy, dpajolz
> 13. oaawz://p.zahjr.ptnby.jvt/nQqTQ.qwn
> 14. 484M574J
>
> $$-\mathfrak{Michael Myers}$$

---

What is Michael trying to tell me?

Comment: *Everything* is simple once you've figured it out. :)

Comment: @Chowzen I agree; I believe the math may have thinned the audience. I removed it since QuantumTwinkie figured out that you can just ROT19 the note. The intended solution was to perform ROT(8, 7, 3, 1) on it to decode. However, it turns out if you just add them together you can decode anyways. The math was $1 + 2 - 3 + 4$ for all four variables, then performing the same math on $a, b, c, d$ would give you $R13(8, 7, 3, 1)$. I've removed this portion of the puzzle as it is already difficult enough without it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you

> Do rot 19 on the text you get

This

> 1. typical horror movie time + female horse
> 2. something incarnate
> 3. the fog was dense, and it was dark; as the night passed by, bone breaking howls broke through the trees; this setting was? e3?
> 4. thiawr (anagram of wraith(synonymy of ghost))
> 5. great horn, barn, snowy, barred, burrowing, elf
> 6. made from a metal frame with several sides (usually four, but up to eight), > commonly with a hook or hoop of metal on top
> 7. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vnWu.jpg
> 8. Metroman is back from the dead!
> 9. Eddie Murphy as Jim Evers
> 10. PSE?73479([could be this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73479/))
> 11. motnahp(anagram of phantom)
> 12. mixture, brew, elixir, witches
> 13. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJjMJ.jpg
> 14. 484F574C

And

> These things seem to be hinting at scary Halloween things, so maybe each hint has to do with a movie?

So

> 1. Night + Mare
> 2. Enchanted
> 3. Errie
> 4.  wraith
> 5. Owl
> 6. Lantern
> 7. Lights
> 8. "Are you a ghost?" is a quote form Megamind the movie
> 9. Haunted Masion
> 10. Y for you
> 11. Phantom
> 12. Potion
> 13. Afraid
> 14. Howl (because T Dude used ascii!)

If the acrostic is corrected then

> It spell "Happy Halloween" backwards.

And a great thanks for some help from [T Dude](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52523/t-dude)!

Comment: Not the intended way to reach the decoded text but okay lol

Comment: Plus you’re missing part

Comment: Hmm good point I will add that!

Comment: @Chowzen You brought forward a good point, but that is the wrong number. :)

Comment: @PerpetualJ edited QT's answer from my incorrect link to the right link. I think?

Comment: @Chowzen Correct! Hopefully I didn't make this puzzle too difficult.

Comment: thiawr = [Wraith](https://www.google.com/search?q=wraith&oq=wraith&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1423j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Hmm good thinking again! I will add that. :D

Comment: Good find @Chowzen and good finds to you as well QuantumTwinkie! +1; The *AND* portion of your answer will lead you down a rabbit hole, though there are technically two movie references here with number 8 probably being the hardest to find as it's probably one of those, *guess what I'm thinking* type answers, but there are technically only two words in that section of the movie that would fit.

Comment: Also, I would like to additionally clarify the *AND* portion of your answer; the movie part will lead you down the rabbit hole. You're right in thinking of scary Halloween things.

Comment: 1 has got to be rot13(avtugzner), 5 is rot13(bjyf)

Comment: Ah nice thinking @TDude I will add that!

Comment: @PerpetualJ how about now? :)

Comment: Answers for 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 (Partially Correct), 11, 12, and 14 are correct; 8 the movie is correct and a simple Google search on the phrase given will pull a YouTube video that should be enlightening. As I stated, there are only two words in that clip that are relevant; it's up to you to determine which fits the best. Also, I should probably point out that every number is a single word.

Comment: Looking at the list of correct answers, I noticed that ROT13(Gur svefg yrggre va rnpu bs gur pbeerpg nafjref svgf gur jbeq arrjbyynulccnu, juvpu pbhyq znxr frafr vs lbh ernq vg onpxjneqf.)

Comment: AMAZING find @BenJ!!

Comment: We got it @PerpetualJ!

Comment: Well for text to be decrypted in Rot19, it must be encrypted in Rot(19-13-1) $=$ Rot7. And the name **Michael** has 7 letters :P

Comment: @user477343 You can also add 1, 3, 7, and 8 to get Rot19 which I didn't know prior and attempted to nest the cipher but to no avail. We live and we learn lol

Comment: QuantumTwinkie +1 and great job on the find! Though the final answer is correct, numbers 2 and 8 are wrong. Number 9 is correct, but only one word is intended for each number. Hint for number two, use anagrams of live. For number 8 there is only one other word in that portion of the movie that would fit and it is synonymous to the one you chose, it starts with an A. As I stated, each number is a single word! :) Good work to all of those involved!

Answer (score 3):

Going off of QuantamTwinkie's list, here's what I've solved so far:

> 1. Nightmare
> 2. Death?  A zombie, maybe?
> 3.
> 4. Wraith
> 5. Owls (or Owl)
> 6. Lantern
> 7.
> 8. Megamind? (quote from MegaMind)
> 9. The Haunted Mansion (film title with that char/actor)
> 10. Asimov (solution to the linked puzzle, answer might include Isaac)
> 11. Phantom
> 12.
> 13.
> 14. HOWL (hex to ascii conversion)